# How to add a D3 graph inside an accordian

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created following graph using D3.js.

[image]

Graph has single *DateTime* X axis, and various Y axis which are layered. There are 3 layers, first with line and rectangles, second with circles and third with rectangles.

*Is there a way to put each layer under an accordion, which could be collapsable/expandable?*

Many thanks.
Sandeep